# Web architecture advice : storing users' data

Tags: cookies, authentication, facebook-login

I am running this online calendar www.workingdays.us

Currently I am storing user's settings and users' custom dates (entries in the calendar) in client cookies.
Advantage : Users don't have to log in, no storage cost on my side. Inconvenient : their settings do not follow them on different desktops and can be lost at any time when cookies are deleted.

I may want to offer a login feature in order to offer more persistence in this storage of users' data.

If I didn't want to store those informations on my server (because it may be private data, because it may represents a large amount of data) which solutions would you advise me for login (do you advise a social login feature ?), and especially for storing users' data in a clever way ?

Answer (score 0):

A social login like Facebook Login is a very good and safe solution, you just need to store the user settings with the Facebook ID. There are also Social Logins for Twitter and Google+ (and some more), but it gets more complicated with every platform - one solution would be to have one "id" field and one "platform" field in your database.

You would still have to store the settings on your server, of course. Or you could use cloud storage like [Parse](https://parse.com/) or [Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/).

Comment: It would be better to be storing the users' data on a space I don't have access to (and I wouldn't have to pay for ; just like cookies now). Can the social login let me also store users' settings on its own social account storage space ? If not, I will be looking more carefully at Parse, at it seems to be a good solution.

Comment: no, you don´t need your own database for the social logins, but they also don´t offer something for settings - so you have to use something like parse of firebase, which would be a good solution. i´d especially take a look at parse.